# What is the keyCode for "$"?

Tags: javascript, keycode

I am trying to disable all other characters from being entered in text input.

Since to get the `$` you have to press the <kbd>shift</kbd>-key and the <kbd>4</kbd>-key. I am not sure how you would get the keyCode for somthing like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the JavaScript KeyCodes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603195/what-are-the-javascript-keycodes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Key codes relate only to keys. `$` is a character, achieved through two keys, Shift and 4.  There is no key code explicitly for `$` *when using `onkeydown`*

Edit: It was pointed out by Edward that `onkeypress` uses key combinations, and does have keycode's for combinations. Learn something new every day :)

[Here's some code](http://jsfiddle.net/eprES/), edited from the `onkeydown` example provided by the MDN, to detect keypress keycodes.

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tHW9x/) updated to be Firefox-friendly, using help from [this S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4496986/1222420). The JQuery solution works too, if you swing that way.

Comment: The fiddle from your edit gives this result in firefox12: 'keyCode for the key pressed: 0' (on any key i press..)

Comment: @GitaarLAB How odd. Works in IE and Chrome. I can't imagine Firefox wouldn't support `onkeypress`, though swapping it for `onkeydown` does work in Firefox.

Comment: Check out [this S.O. thread for info on onkeypress in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496910/onkeypress-event-not-working-in-firefox) Doubt its the only one too

Comment: I'm losing faith in firefox to (apart from the security risks it starts to pose).. But on subject: yeah, does not matter what key I press, also does not respond to shift of alt or ctrl..

Comment: @GitaarLAB Added another fiddle to be Firefox-friendly

Comment: Confirm, works!! Nice one. Alway's fun here on SO: you answered the question that was asked in the title, whereas I provided a different view on how to obtain the same end-result as outlined in the question's text. I like my answer to but I'm gonna vote for your answer to, since users mostly find answers related to the title of the question! Nice job!

Answer (score 6):

There is no `onkeydown` keycode, as previously said by **ngmiceli**

Although, `onkeypress` keycode exists and is equal to `36`.

[JavaScript Event KeyCode Test Page](http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html)

Answer (score 2):

Then DONT use this way to solve your problem: since you cannot predict that every keyboard-layout will always have $-sign entered as shift+4.
You can still get keycode 4, and check if shift was pressed, but you could not be sure of this!!

Thus **it would be better to simply replace all illegal characters in your fields** (before you submit the data).  Think: str.replace()
You could also check for your set of illegal characters on the onkeyup event of the input-box, effectively replacing all illegal characters as you type!
Like: `onkeyup="this.value.replace(/[your illegal characters]/gi, '')"`
That should do what you want.

Please note: you should NEVER trust browser-input, and should still filter this input in your receiving script!!!

Good Luck!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no key code for `$`, since it's not a valid key - it has to be accessed via some kind of shifter.

Usually, you would perform a check to see if the shifter was active, and the listen out for the `keypress` event on the relevant key. Something like this for a QWERTY layout in your instance:

```
var shiftPressed = false;

$(window).keydown(function(e) {  
    if(e.which == 16) { shiftPressed = true; }
    if(e.which == 52 && shiftPressed) 
    {  
        // Do whatever here...
    }
});

$(window).keyup(function(e) {  
    if(e.which == 16) { shiftPressed = false; }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

onkeypress - The Unicode CHARACTER code is: 36

onkeydown - The Unicode KEY code is: 52