# How to find out the key pressed on keyup or keypress event when dollar key is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, onkeyup

The below method returns any key from A-Z and 0-9 and when I pressed shift key + 4 its returns the same code 52.

```
function keyUpEvent(e)//onkeyup event
{
    var chr = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);//converts the keycode into a character
    alert(chr);//alerts the character
}
```

But I need to show the **$ or %** when the respective key with combination of shift key is pressed.

Comment: Seriously, you don't need to write the title 3 times.

Comment: Like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/bd3PQ/) ???

Comment: okay i will correct it next time. but Stackoverflow is not letting to submit short questions. that is why i made it lengthier.. Sorry for that..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i'd go with something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('keyup keydown keypress', function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 52 && event.shiftKey) {
            alert('foo');
        }
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C7PZB/)

Answer (score 2):

Key codes relate only to keys. `$` is a character, achieved through two keys, Shift and 4.  There is no key code explicitly for `$` *when using `onkeydown`*

Edit: It was pointed out by Edward that `onkeypress` uses key combinations, and does have keycode's for combinations. Learn something new every day :)

[Here's some code](http://jsfiddle.net/eprES/), edited from the `onkeydown` example provided by the MDN, to detect keypress keycodes.

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tHW9x/) updated to be Firefox-friendly, using help from [this S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4496986/1222420). The JQuery solution works too, if you swing that way.

$ is equal to `36`.

[JavaScript Event KeyCode Test Page](http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html)

Here is same [S.O thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868643/what-is-the-keycode-for/11868743#11868743)

Comment: +1 - good answer, but when you copy answers from other users, at least add a link back : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868643/what-is-the-keycode-for

Comment: Please add your code to your answer; if jsFiddle is down, this answer is useless.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot check for two key events at once. You can try e.shiftKey which tells you whether the shift key was being pressed when the event occurred. Try to check:

```
if(e.keyCode === 53 && e.shiftKey){}
```

also if you have a text field, than you can attach event on key enter and check for '%'.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.shiftKey

thanks to Marcel Korpel

Comment: There's an `e.shiftKey`; see http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html. This answer assumes that the Shift key has been pressed immediately before the `5`, but it there could be intermediate keys pressed or the Shift key could be released before `5` is pressed.

Comment: Yes. Very correct. The shift key has to be pressed down while the event is being fired.

Comment: Yes, and you can't be sure with your pseudocode that it is still down. Use `e.shiftKey` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In `KeyDown` event of `TextBox`, use:

```
if (e.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.4) {
  //Your code here
}
```

Comment: Please make sure that you are doing this code on `keydown` event because IE doesn't support `keypress` event.

Comment: okay..i am trying it in onKeyUp event..and it was not working

Comment: This is not an answer. Events have a `shiftKey` property as mentioned by others, but no `Shift` (nor even a `shift`) property, and they have a `keyCode` property but no `KeyCode` property. And, as far as I can tell, no browser has a `Keys` global either.