# Is it possible to have a transformation in Javascript without a trigger?

Tags: javascript, css

Please note that I am a noobie in JS (1st or 2nd day), and so this question probably seems ridiculous to most of you.

however, I'm trying to implant JS into a project I've been doing. I'm attempting to scale up a image after another object is scaled down (in this case the header), however, for some odd reason it just pops up, no scale, no transition, any clues as to why?

```js
function fadeIn(){
    var el = document.querySelector("h1");
    el.style.opacity= 1;
    el.style.transition="opacity 1.0s linear 0s";
}

window.addEventListener("keypress",checkKeyPress,false);


function checkKeyPress(key){
    var el = document.querySelector("h1");
    var el2 = document.querySelector(".main");
    var el3 = document.querySelector(".text");
    var el4 = document.getElementById("logo");
    if(key.keyCode=="36"){
        el.style.opacity=0;
        setTimeout(function() {
            el.style.display="none";
            el3.style.display="none";
            el2.style.display="inline";
            el4.style.height="800px";
            el4.style.transition="height 1.0s linear 0s";
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

```css
    *{
    font-family: helvetica;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;

}
body{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:black;
}
.text{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
        ". . ."
        ". center ."
        ". . .";
}
h1{
    grid-area: center;
    color: white;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: center;
    opacity: 0;
}
.main{
    display: none;
}
.container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 12fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
    ". logo ."
    ". form ."
    ". . ."
}
#logo{
    grid-area: logo;
    height: 0px;
}
#form{
    grid-area: form;
    justify-self: center;
}
#password{
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 21px;
    width: 170px;
    border-style: none;
    border-radius: 6px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
}
label{
    color: white;
    padding-right: 3px;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
}
#submit{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
    <body onload="fadeIn()">
    <div class="text">
        <h1>Why are you here?</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="container">
                <img src="http://t15.deviantart.net/iy-wsIkQ2wP7g08wOsW4mi_daNM=/fit-in/700x350/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre14/e387/th/pre/f/2010/096/1/b/dollars___logo_vector_by_xxkaiserxx.png" alt="dollars logo" id="logo">
                <form action="../php/index.php" method="post" id="form">
                    <label for="password">PASSWORD:</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" maxlength="16" required>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" required>
                </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

> [Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4Luf5451/) for the above question

Fixed!

By adding another setTimeout function, we are able to postpone the expansion and correctly expand the logo.

Update JS:

```
function fadeIn(){
    var el = document.querySelector("h1");
    el.style.opacity= 1;
    el.style.transition="opacity 1.0s ease-in-out 0s";
}

window.addEventListener("keypress",checkKeyPress,false);


function checkKeyPress(key){
    var el = document.querySelector("h1");
    var el2 = document.querySelector(".main");
    var el3 = document.querySelector(".text");
    var el4 = document.getElementById("logo");
    if(key.keyCode=="36"){
        el.style.opacity=0;
        setTimeout(function() {
            el.style.display="none";
            el3.style.display="none";
            el2.style.display="block";
            setTimeout(function(){
                el4.style.transition = "all 1.0s ease-in-out";
                el4.style.transform = "scale(1) rotate(0deg)";
            },50);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give us jsfiddle of what you are trying to do? also, what is inside the fadeIn() function?

Comment: @Redan inside the fadeIn() function is text. there should be a code snippet available now.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```js
function fadeIn() {
  var el = document.querySelector("h1");
  el.style.opacity = 1;
  el.style.transition = "opacity 1.0s linear 0s";
}

window.addEventListener("keypress", checkKeyPress, false);


  
function checkKeyPress(key) {
  var el = document.querySelector("h1");
  var el2 = document.querySelector(".main");
  var el3 = document.querySelector(".text");
  var el4 = document.getElementById("logo");
  el4.style.height= 0;
  if (key.keyCode == "36") {
    el.style.opacity = 0;
    setTimeout(function() {
      el.style.display = "none";
      el3.style.display = "none";
      el2.style.display = "inline";
      el4.className += " height";
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: helvetica;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.text {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: ". . ." ". center ." ". . .";
}

h1 {
  grid-area: center;
  color: white;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  opacity: 0;
}
.height{
  width:100px;
  animation: anim 1.0s linear 0s forwards;
}
@keyframes anim{
 0%{
  height:0px;
 -ms-transform: scale(0); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: scale(0); /* Safari */
transform: scale(0);
 }
  100%{
    height:800px;
     -ms-transform: scale(1); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1); /* Safari */
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
.main {
  display: none;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 12fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: ". logo ." ". form ." ". . ."
}

#logo {
  grid-area: logo;
}

#form {
  grid-area: form;
  justify-self: center;
}

#password {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 21px;
  width: 170px;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
}

label {
  color: white;
  padding-right: 3px;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

#submit {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body onload="fadeIn()">
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Why are you here?</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="http://t15.deviantart.net/iy-wsIkQ2wP7g08wOsW4mi_daNM=/fit-in/700x350/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre14/e387/th/pre/f/2010/096/1/b/dollars___logo_vector_by_xxkaiserxx.png" alt="dollars logo" id="logo">
      <form action="../php/index.php" method="post" id="form">
        <label for="password">PASSWORD:</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" maxlength="16" required>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" required>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Keycode 36 is the $ sign, so in this case the key up function would not work, any other suggestions?

Comment: @UrmzdMu use keypress. I change it to keypress. Try to press $.

Comment: it works, however, would it also function if lets say the height was 800px but the scale differed from 0 - 1

Comment: @UrmzdMu have you tried it with height:800px and scale?

Comment: yes, it doesnt work for some reason? any clues as to why? @shadowfiend

Comment: @UrmzdMu what is the scale value that you use?

Comment: from scale 0 to scale 1

Comment: @UrmzdMu just mark this as the answer if it solve your problem :)

Comment: one more question sorry, but the scale is weird it scales while height increases, if you remove the height aspect and leave the default height + width and just scale from 0 - 1, would a smoother transition occur?

Comment: yup, it just expands upwards @shadowfiend, however I fixed the function by adding another settimeout function. It works fine now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
window.addEventListener("keyup",checkKeyPress,false);
```

Comment: keycode 36 is the $ symbol, so the keyup event in this case would not work,  any other suggestions?

Comment: Keycode 36 is the home button, have a look at this table.  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/. $ is not a key on the keyboard but a character https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868643/what-is-the-keycode-for

Comment: w3.org/2002/09/tests/keys.html when attempting the keycode 36 on this website and it seems as the values differ on keyup keydown and keypress.