# enter key pressed call javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cross-browser, keycode

I have an asp:TextBox on my page and I would like to detect the enter key to call a javascript function. This is what I have:

Codebehind

```
txtSearch.Attributes.Add("OnKeyPress", "ProcessKeyPressed()")
```

aspx page

```
 function ProcessKeyPressed() {
    if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 10 ) {
        Search();
    }
 }
```

This works in chrome and IE, but not in Firefox...any idea why this might be the case?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Does not work how?  Does the ProcessKeyPressed function not get called at all?  Is there any error?  Have you used the Firefox JavaScript console or Firebug to check for errors?

Comment: possible duplicate of [onKeyPress event not working in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496910/onkeypress-event-not-working-in-firefox) (you should check the second answer)

Comment: Yep you're right tpeczek, my question is for that same issue. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
function ProcessKeyPressed(event) {
   if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 10 ) {
       Search();
   }
}
```

See here for more info: [window.event.keyCode how to do it on Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116933/window-event-keycode-how-to-do-it-on-firefox)

Comment: I tried the same but not working on custom control textbox my code is-----<ucCustomTextBox:CustomTextBox ID="txtCurrentTelNo" runat="server" TabIndex="28" ControlCSS="input_textarea w190 allcaps"  MaxLength="18" ControlType="Numeric"  MinimumLength="0" IsOnline="true" ControlName="Telephone number"  EnableEvent="True" onkeypress="return ProcessKeyPressed(event)"  EnableJavascript="True" IsRequired="True" /> and Function on aspx ...                                            function ProcessKeyPressed(event) {
   if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 10 ) {
       Search();
   }
}

Answer (score 1):

Code behind:

```
txtSearch.Attributes.Add("OnKeyPress", "ProcessKeyPressed(event || window.event)")
```

And JS:

```
function ProcessKeyPressed(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 10 ) {
        Search();
    }
 }
```

Based on [this](http://javascript.info/tutorial/obtaining-event-object#cross-browser-solution)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ReALs/)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
function ProcessKeyPressed(e) {
    var event = e || window.event;
    var key = event.charCode || event.keyCode
    if (key == 13 || key == 10 ) {
        Search();
    }
}
```