# Event object not found in Mozilla onkeypress but works on chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I was checking some code and found an issue that on key press a JS event is called with no parameter passed and he consoles the event. The event object gets displayed in chrome but not on Mozilla.

Please find the sample code below:
HTML

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="func()"/>
```

JS

```
function func(){
 console.log(event);
}
```

The above works fine in chromium but not on Mozilla.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12928631/6003350 Please check this out

Comment: To log the event object you must put an 'event' parameter between the function parenthesis to receive it as a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across situations like this as well. Passing the event as a param to the function works, both in Chrome and in Firefox.

Maybe this will help.

[How to pass event as argument to an inline event handler in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404327/how-to-pass-event-as-argument-to-an-inline-event-handler-in-javascript)